# tlp vs laptop-mod-tools

Tags: power-management

my laptop battery got empty soon and I installed bumblebee and tlp, now I have about 3hour battery energy more than before on my laptop.
and now I found there is an other powermanagement for ubuntu laptop-mod-tools.
which one is the best for powermanagement on ubuntu 13.04 ? tlp or laptop-mod-tools?

Answer (score -1):

Power management is built-in, tested and automatic with Ubuntu 13.04. How well it works depends on the condition, make and model of your battery and laptop.

Bumblebee does provide other functionality that is not built-in, as many laptops don't have the hardware that it manages.

TLP can be problematic and needs a lot of custom configuration. Laptop-tools is not needed anymore, all it's functions are now built-in.

I suspect most of the change you see is from Bumblebee, but I have not seen any objective, scientific tests on any of this. You can and should do your own experiments.

Comment: >Laptop-tools is not needed anymore, all it's functions are now built-in.

Built in what? Source needed.